# .change() not trigged when <select> changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here `HTML` part:

```
<select id="select_refresh">
  <option value="Never">Never</option>
  <option value="1 second">1 second</option>
  <option value="5 seconds">5 seconds</option>
  <option value="15 seconds">15 seconds</option>
</select>
```

here `javascript` part:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
   function handleSelectChange(){
           console.log("trigged!!!");
   }

   $("#select_refresh").change(handleSelectChange);
})
```

When I enter `html` page and change selected option , I cannot see print in console.

What i am doing wrong ?

Many thanks!

Comment: I can see a syntax error. missing `)` for the `ready` function.

Comment: Is working http://jsfiddle.net/jq4xytea/1/ . Just close ready function as @undefined mention.

Comment: My bad. Bad copy/paste. Source code is correct.

Comment: Check the browser console for errors, your code looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `);` at the end:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
   function handleSelectChange(){
           console.log("trigged!!!");
   }

   $("#select_refresh").change(handleSelectChange);
});
```

**[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nasp1f2b/)**

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing your function right
this:

```
 $(document).ready ( function(){
   function handleSelectChange(){
           console.log("trigged!!!");
   }

   $("#select_refresh").change(handleSelectChange);
}
```

should be:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
   function handleSelectChange(){
           console.log("trigged!!!");
   }

   $("#select_refresh").change(handleSelectChange);
});
```

You forgat to add the ); that is openened after the ready ( func